# Play Framework JSON reader

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to read JSON in following format

```
[
{type: "city",name:"Paris",lan:10.1,lot:20.0},
{type: "country",name:"France",...}

]
```

to Array[GeoObject] where GeoObject is parent for Country and City classes

how can I do this trick with Json Readers ? I have tryed something like

```
def mkObject(..,type:String,..):GeoObject = type match {
case 'city' => City(...)
case 'country' => Country(...)
}
implicit val geoobjectReads = (
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
....
)(mkObject _)
```

but without success.

And actually I have the other different question.

I have in JSON two fields 'lan','lot' - but GeoObject has only one

```
coordinates:LanLot
```

where LanLot is just case class with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also want to make json reads/writes for your coordinates if you want them in a separate case class, and they can be parsed as a nested object inside `GeoObject`. You were definitely on the right track, though.

Putting it all together:

```
case class Coordinates(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

object Coordinates {

    implicit val jsonReads: Reads[Coordinates] = (
        (__ \ "latitude").read[Double] and 
        (__ \ "longitude").read[Double]
    )(Coordinates.apply _)

}

class GeoObject(`type`: String, name: String, coordinates: Coordinates)

object GeoObject {

    def apply(`type`: String, name: String, coordinates: Coordinates) = {
        `type` match {
            case "city" => City(`type`, name, coordinates)
            case "country" => Country(`type`, name, coordinates)
        }
    }

    implicit val jsonReads: Reads[GeoObject] = (
        (__ \ "type").read[String] and 
        (__ \ "name").read[String] and 
        (__ \ "coordinates").read[Coordinates]
    )(GeoObject.apply _)

 }

case class City(`type`: String, name: String, coordinates: Coordinates) extends GeoObject(`type`, name, coordinates)

case class Country(`type`: String, name: String, coordinates: Coordinates) extends GeoObject(`type`, name, coordinates)
```

And in action (`play console`):

```
scala> Json.parse("""{"type":"city", "name": "New York", "coordinates": {"latitude": 40.77, "longitude": -73.92}}""").as[GeoObject]
res2: GeoObject = City(city,New York,Coordinates(40.77,-73.92))
```

I overrode `GeoObject.apply` to always convert to `City` or `Country`, but you can use whatever function you want.

**Edit:** I went ahead and used `type` with backticks as Vikas pointed out.

Comment: you can still use `type` as a variable name with backticks. scala> val `type` = "abc"
type: String = abc. SO formatting is screwing up my backticks but val type has backticks in there

Comment: Fair enough. Ugly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of Play! json read syntax.
So I would prefer to use Json Inception to read into temporary case class, and then I would convert from one case class to another in the code explicitly.

Something like this. I replaced `type` with `typ`, to avoid code pollution with backticks.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

// let's just define all the structures you need
case class Coordinates(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

abstract class GeoObject {
  def typ: String
  def name: String
  def coordinates: Coordinates
}

val CityType = "city"
val CountryType = "country"

case class City(name: String, coordinates: Coordinates) extends GeoObject {
  val typ = CityType
}

case class Country(name: String, coordinates: Coordinates) extends GeoObject {
  val typ = CountryType
}

// case class representing json
case class GeoObjectJson(typ: String, name: String, lat: Double, long: Double)
implicit val geoObjectJsonReads = Json.reads[GeoObjectJson]

// companion object (as a factory)
object GeoObject {

  def apply(geoJson: GeoObjectJson): GeoObject = {
    val coord = Coordinates(geoJson.lat, geoJson.long)
    geoJson.typ match {
      case CityType => City(geoJson.name, coord)
      case CountryType => Country(geoJson.name, coord)
    }
  }
}
// tests

val cityJsonString = """{"typ":"city", "name": "New York", "lat": 40.77, "long": -73.92}"""
val cityJson = Json.parse(cityJsonString).as[GeoObjectJson]
val cityGeoObject = GeoObject(cityJson)
// City(New York,Coordinates(40.77,-73.92))
val countryJsonString = """{"typ":"country", "name": "Canada", "lat": 40.77, "long": -73.92}"""
val countryJson = Json.parse(countryJsonString).as[GeoObjectJson]
val countryGeoObject = GeoObject(countryJson)
// Country(Canada,Coordinates(40.77,-73.92))
```

Comment: JSON inception becomes pretty useless as soon as you want to include any kind of validation (location type constraints, coordinate bounds).  I'll agree that the syntax isn't the best for defining reads/writes, but it's still worth learning.